# Secure correct money amount when people checkout?

Tags: php, payment-processing

I have a problem that i seems can't figure out properly.
I got a website where you can pick some offer and buy it. 
The steps for this procedure is:

1) Customer pick offer (index.php) he like and proceed to (buy.php) page

2) At (buy.php) page he selects quantity and payment method

3) When customer presses buy he is redirected to (payment.php) where all data is verified again and doing some database recording. Payment.php page processes user to selected payment gateway (out of my website).

So the problem is that i can swap $_POST data from buy.php page to payment.php and payment page would think that data is correct.

Before i was simply checking if price that comes to payment page is one of allowed prices in my $array and i had no problems with this. But now i offer a discounts and i can not tell if amount coming in is indeed correct.

How usually all this is processed? I'm new to working with payments.

Thanks.

Comment: Never transport payment data in user accessible POST variables. Use [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php). Do the final calculation of the amount based only on session data.

Comment: As good practice you shouldn't accept prices from users whether you filter them or not. It's best to associate prices with product or offer ids in your DB that have price fields instead. Also do be sure to use HTTPS when transferring credit card data. I believe it is the law for US hosted sites.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder, the [PCI](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/index.php) requirements for credit card processing are much more complex than just "use https". The PCI standards are complex enough that most people just use a merchant account with a payment gateway, as @arma is doing.

Comment: My website is not processing actual credit card inputs i send cutomer to 3rd party (bank or other). The thing is i seems can't figure out how to work with no static prices. Like if i got quantity 10 and price is $1 then it's easy to secure correct amount, but what if we have discounts then price would differ from DB prices.

Comment: @sarnold Thanks for the link. I think I'll leave all my cc processing to paypal. @arma Try a db table of product id's with prices and a table of discounts with the amount (or percent). When the users submits an order, send the ids of products with their respective quantities along with the ids of any discounts to the payment script. Let it handle the final price calculation.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder yeah i was just thinking about doing that. I send Quantity + Bonus code (if present) and then on next page calculate all and register payment with correct amount to payment merchant and when i get unique trans id back from merchant i can securely send customer to 3rd party website. Even if user manages to swap anything  at last point in my website trans id data will be different.

Comment: @arma Right, that way the user can't forge the total cost (Imagine if that were possible on popular sites like Amazon...what a mess that would be!)

Comment: @phpmycoder: My thoughts exactly. :)

Comment: @sarnold Sounds like something a novice and very naive hacker would try: amazon.com/gold-watch?price=0.00 L0L I HAX0R THE INTERWEBS!!!11

Comment: @PhpMyCoder would you mind to copy/paste your 2nd response as answer so i can Accept answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way payment providers do this, is the following.

- You have a form that will result in a POST array.
- add one field to this array with a hash. Make this hash from the string as follows:

  - Define a secret string (some sort of a 'salt', but different)
  - Sort all your POST keys alphabetically.
  - Make a string like this:
  - key=value.secretString.key2=value2.secretString ... etc
  - hash the string and send it in the post.
  - (do NOT send, show or reveal your secret string, obviously)

Now when you receive the POST, you can use your secret string to recreate the hash that should accompany it, and compare it to the hash you got (also in the post ofcourse, obviously don't hash that too). If it is equal, the values where not tampered with. If it isn't you should reject the payment.

Because you also include a date, a user/orderID etc in your post, it cannot be changed for the post of another order. Changing one of the values in the post would also mean the HASH has to be changed, but as the user can't create it, this will not do.

Comment: Thanks for commenting so i can mark some answer :) But yeah i got it sorted now already. I simply use quantity and product id and pass them to the next page where requests to payment merchant is made and futher there is no way ( only by hacking payment merchant ) to mess with stuff. And if people mess with id and quantities that gives them nothing but different product with different quantities and all prices are correctly applied.

Answer (score 2):

Try a db table of product id's with prices and a table of discounts with the amount (or percent). When the users submits an order, send the ids of products with their respective quantities along with the ids of any discounts to the payment script. Let it handle the final price calculation.